# Create two threads

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, operating-system, computer-science

Create two threads (let’s call them T1 and T2). T1 should print “I am T1”, T2 should print “I am T2”. The main thread (the thread that creates T1 and T2) should wait for them. o There should be a shared variable x that is initialized to 10. T1 should increment x by 5, T2 should increment x by 100. o Then, after T1 and T2 are done, the main process should print “I am the main thread, the two threads are done”. Also, the main thread should print the last value of x.

Comment: This sounds like a homework problem. Are you trying to get us to do your work for you? Have you even written any code of your own yet? If so, please add it to your post, and tell us what problems you are having with it.

Comment: @Ahmad welcome to stackoverflow, have you try something, maybe a rough outline of your code

Comment: Ok create two threads.

Comment: Right on it! Where can I hand in the assignment for my credits?

Answer (score 2):

i don't know exactly what's your question, but let me try:

1. you need to create T1 and T2
2. t1 and t2 should print 'i am..' mesages on constructor
3. both threads should increment the same x variable
4. then after those two guys are done the main thread print a mesage
5. the main thread need to print the x value

here it is:

```
import threading

x = 10

class T1 (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(T1 , self).__init__(name="T1 thread")
        print 'I am T1'

    def run(self):
        global x
        x += 5


class T2 (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(T2 , self).__init__(name="T2 thread")
        print 'I am T2'

    def run(self):
        global x
        x += 100

t1 = T1()
t2 = T2()

t1.start()
t2.start()

while t1.is_alive() or t2.isAlive():
    pass

print "t1 and t2 are done"
print x
```

since you don't use any kind of list or data structure that should work, but remember to check this link if you pretend to use any list, line, stack, etc.
[Python Multithreaded Programming](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm)

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
import threading
x = 10
def prints(Text,increment):
    global x
    print Text
    x += increment

thread1 = threading.Thread(target=prints, args=("I am T1\n",5))
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=prints, args=("I am T2\n",100)) #Create threads and pass arguments to function
thread1.start()
thread2.start()             #Start threads

thread1.join()      #Wait until thread1 has finished execution
thread2.join()      #Wait until thread2 has finished execution
print "I am the main thread, the two threads are done"
print x
raw_input("") #Just to prevent window from closing
```